# How to make big game run more smoothly?

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, flash-cs5

I am developing a ipad game using flash CS5. When I run it in flash or web browser, it run quite smoothly but when I published it into ipa file and run it on my own ipad, it became very very slow. Since my game has many stages and characters, the amount of symbols may up to more than 50. That makes the flash file more than 100mb (but the ipa is only 11mb) All of the symbols are exported in frame 1.

Therefore, I have some questions wish to understand:

1)if I used preloader and exports the symbols in frame 2, will my game run more smoothly? is one preloader when the game is loaded enough? or it is need for every game scenes?

2)Is there any other technique that a big game developed in Flash has to follow in order can be run in low configurations devices?

3)Why many other big game can run so smoothly although it contains a lot more characters and background than mine?

Thank you a lot for your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) All the preloader will do is show your users that something is going on until the game starts. It will not affect game performance.

2) Yes: You have to optimize every calculation and every asset for small memory footprint and fast performance. Start [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/optimize_content_ios.html).

3) Because they spent a lot of time on 2)

On a side note: It is usually a good idea to have a main game loop, and do all the calculations in your game logic prior to a single rendering step, instead of having lots of independent timelines. In the rendering step, you can exclude and/or minimize all the efforts on objects that are out of sight, or not entirely visible.

Comment: thx u ^^ Could you explain what is the job of preloader in every scene of the big games, since all the symbols has already load when the game has started? That the biggest confusion I got.

Comment: You don't put a preloader in every scene.  You would only need it once - to show until the game is fully loaded.  To be honest with you: I can't even say for sure single-file preloaders will work on iOS. I can't say I've seen any so far; it's usually just splash screens.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got your comment wrong: The "big" games probably load videos, maps, textures, game data. And they are often done in Cocoa.

Comment: Then is it totally different to Flash? I can not just load the map and textures only in the beginning of the scene in Flash? ?.?

Comment: No, you just can't load runnable SWFs with Flash. You can load as much data as you like.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to keep in mind:

- Upgrade to Flash CS5.5
- Use flashplayer 11.0
- Use AIR3.1 SDK
- Publish using "GPU" (not CPU)
- [Object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)!
- Try using as much bitmaps as possible, vectors are "heavier".
- 'cacheAsBitmap' only on objects that move along the x / y axes
- Alpha transparencies eat up your CPU
- Did I mention [Object pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern)?
- Attach a FPS monitor to your app, so you can keep track of frame-rate drops.

Comment: Thank u a lot! That's really helpful to me :D if u can think of any other hint please tell me, thx ^^

Answer (score -1):

Do yourself a favour and ditch Flash. Write your game in Objective C / C / C++

Even Adobe and Microsoft are abandoning Flash for Mobile devices.

Btw, I'm no Flash hater - I've been a "Flash developer" since FutureSplash and still use the Flash  IDE where appropriate, but not when targeting mobile devices.

Comment: Adobe abandoning flash? Sure they dropped support for mobile flash players, but they're surely not ruling out app / game development. Maybe flash for web-development isn't as popular as it's used to be. But flash (air) is still the number 1 choice for game development on the web AND mobile. I think mobile game development in flash will even grow upcoming years.

Comment: The OP is talking about creating a game for ipad/iphone as an ipa and not desktop web use. The fact that cannot be denied is that Adobe and Microsoft HAVE abandoned Flash as a viable option for mobile devices. Not for web (yet) but definitely for mobiles. Yes Flash is still the best choice for desktop device web games, but for mobile games it's a very poor choice unless the game is simple (i.e. not the type of game the OP is talking about).

Comment: I am not talking about web, I'm talking about mobile. They have definitely NOT dropped flash for mobile devices. If I'm not mistaken they more and more focussing flash for multi-platform usage and mobile is a big part of that, hence the updates for AIR.

Comment: I didn't mention web until you did.  I'm talking about mobile too. Flash is old slow technology and will never compete with native coding in a C variant. This thread was about performance. If performance is an issue, forget Flash.